# Translation of one of the languages is not displayed on the site

Tags: plugin-wpml

I use Upstore theme and the website has 2 languages (Estonian and Russian).
I translate some strings from WPML String translation from English to EST and RUS. But on the website only Russian translations are shown. In Estonian version strings are still in English.

Comment: Hello! Third party plugins (like WPML) are off topic here, sorry. You can ask via their official support forums instead.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.